# Inserting content on a page and applyign theme to it in LIferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have created a theme and I want to apply it for a page in liferay. I tried creating a page but I don't know where to insert content in it. 
Further the theme that I have created has a header and footer and the page info should come in between these two. So how do I put the page in a theme?

Also where should I insert the data on a page?

EDIT:

BY data I do not mean portlet but the data that will be added by the user in future and not by the developer. Because the pages that will be developed will be applied themes and content of that page should be made modifiable by user in future. User meaning the admin who will be handling the website.

Comment: First you have to create page and then applied the theme on it and for the content you can add webcontent from the control panel and show that content with the webcontent display portlet which you are going to put on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply theme to a page using following below steps.

- `Control Panel`
- Select your Site from left Panel(By default it would site from which you accessing Control  Panel)
- Click on `Site Pages`
- Click on Page Name to which you want to apply theme (Public or Private)
- Select `Look and feel` from right side panel
- check radio button corresponding to  `Define a specific look and feel for this page.`
- Select your theme from  `Available Themes`  section
- Click save.

  **where should I insert the data on a page?**

  I assuming data means you want to add Portlet to page, that you can do it by clicking on Add -> More -> Search for your portlet and click on add.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gautam. BY data I html content and not portlet. I would want the data to be added by the user in future and not the developer.

Comment: @user2822187 yeah that you can do by adding portlet to a page

Comment: I want to make a header and footer for the page too.. WHich will not be changed by the user. SoI guess I will need to separate portlets each for header and a footer.Isnt it?

Comment: Header and footer you can put in your theme

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. So whatever the user will change will go in the portlet. Other stuff I will put in themes

Answer (score 1):

You'll always add data to the page by adding portlets to the page, that's the concept of a portal. Who is able to add portlets to the page, as well as who's able to change the content that's shown by the portlets, is configurable - e.g. dependent on permissions that you can configure.

For example: If you just want to add some text (content) to the page, add a "Web Content Display" Portlet to the page (make sure to have "Edit Controls" checked in order to see it): This will display a semi-transparent portlet on the page (because it doesn't have any content yet). You can now either write a new article (see the controls on that portlet) or choose an already existing article from the underlying CMS.

As I don't fully understand your question, I hope that this provides a direction for your discovery of Liferay's UI